# Keywords meta tags are not being updated

Tags: magento2.2, meta-tags

When I change the **Meta Keywords** in **Search Engine Optimization** and check the result with the **Developer Tools** of my browser, I can't see any change.

I tried removing the browser cache and cleaning **Magento** this way:

```
cd /var/www/html/MAGENTO_FOLDER
rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cron:run
```

But it doesn't solve the issue.

Is it a bug from **Magento 2.2** or is there something else I should do to refresh the **Meta Keywords** tags ?

Comment: If you are running varnish this would also need to be refreshed. Is this a custom theme or luma/blank?

Comment: It's a custom theme

Comment: As a quick test, switch to luma or blank and refresh the cache etc and check if it is updating.

Comment: The problem came from the scope, I was editing at scope "All Store Views" while I have to edit at the scope of the specific store view my website is using. Magento is opening the product at scope "All Store Views" by default, which is a bit troublesome, I don't know if there's a way to disable this "All Store Views" scope.

Comment: Magento 2 has a setting for running as a single store but I think you'll still run into the store view issue.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately single store option works only with single website mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have more than one website and I was editing the product in "All Store Views" of a website, instead of selecting the "Store View" of the website.